# How to make Right asterisk triangle using while loop

Tags: python

This is the code I have, but I keep getting left triangles:

```
def RTriangle(n):
    row =  1 
    while row <= n:
        col = 1
        while col <= row:
            print("*", end="")
            col = col + 1
        print()
        row = row - 1


def test_rt():
    for i in range(5, 12, 3):
        RTriangle(i)
        print()

test_rt()
```

Comment: Tip: You need to print the spaces before the `'*'`.

Comment: Please show us what a "Right asterisk triangle" is supposed to look like. As it is now your question is not easy to understand.

Comment: JE3 by right asterisk triangle do you mean like this:  ◣ or like this: ◢ or like this: ◤ or like this: ◥?

Comment: like this  ◢ , everyone knows what a right triangle is, just think of it made up with asterisks @Maurice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can actually multiply a string (this will copy the string x times), which means you don't have to print it out one by one. For example, `"cat" * 3` gives `"catcatcat"`

**Here is the solution:**

```
def RTriangle(n):
    col = 0 
    while col <= n:
        print(" " * (n - col),"*" * col)
        col = col + 1

def test_rt():
    for i in range(5, 12, 3):
        RTriangle(i)
        print()

test_rt()
```